# $\int_0^{x^{3/4}} t^{2/3} \sin \frac{1}{t} \, dt$ continuous on $[0 , 3]$ by fundamental Theorem of calculus.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How to show that this-$\displaystyle\int_0^{x^{\frac{3}{4}}} t^{\frac{2}{3}} \sin{\frac{1}{t} }dt$ is continuous on $[0 , 3]$ by applying fundamental Theorem of calculus.

My Attempt : $\displaystyle\int_0^{x^{\frac{3}{4}}} t^{\frac{2}{3}} \sin{\frac{1}{t} }dt  = \displaystyle\int_0^x {t^{\frac{1}{4}}} \sin{\frac{1}{t^{\frac{3}{4}}} }dt$$..

Now I will consider the Right side of the equation.The integrand is integrable on $[ 0 , 3]$. So by fundamental theorem of calculus we can say $\displaystyle\int_0^{x^{\frac{3}{4}}} t^{\frac{2}{3}} \sin{\frac{1}{t} }dt$  is continuous on $[0 ,3]$

Comment: Are you able to use the fact that a function being differentiable (on an interval) implies the function is continuous (on that interval)?

Comment: Yes I can prove that.. @EricTowers

Comment: Observe that the given integral reduces to $$\frac 3 4 \int_{0}^{x} t^{\frac 7 4} \sin \frac {1} {t^{\frac 3 4}}\ dt.$$ Now can you finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}[1]{\text{ d}#1}$
[FTOC #1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) asserts that the integral of any continuous function over $[a,b]$ is continuous. The function:
$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
t^{\frac{2}{3}} \sin\frac{1}{t}, &\text{if $x \in (0, 3]$} \\
0, &\text{if $x = 0$} 
\end{cases}
$$
is continuous on $[0,3]$, so $\int_0^x f(t) \d{t} = \int_0^x t^{\frac{2}{3}} \sin\frac{1}{t} \d{t}$ is continuous. Now the map $x \mapsto x^{\frac{3}{4}}$ is continuous, and composing it with the integral yields $\int_0^{x^\frac{3}{4}} t^{\frac{2}{3}} \sin\frac{1}{t} \d{t}$. Since composition of continuous functions is continuous, the result follows.